# detect scaling problem form performance test result

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, scalability, blazemeter

I conducted performance testing on e-commerce website and I have the test results with some matrices. I already found some problems on some component for example on checkout or post login with high response time and error. But I also would like to find issues that are limiting the application to scale. I only did the testing on the application server. And I observed that CPU , I/O rate are very stable as well. But still the application gives high response time. Is there any other way I can determine from the test result why it is not scaling well? Thank!

Answer (score 0):

From JMeter test result only - unlikely, JMeter just sends requests, waits for the responses and measures the time in-between plus collects some extra metrics like connect time and latency, see the [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for full list with explanations

The integrated system acts at the speed of its slowest component,  possible reasons could be in:

1. [Network issues](https://obkio.com/blog/common-network-problems/) (i.e. lack of bandwidth, faulty router, long DNS resolution time, etc.)
2. Your application is not properly configured for high loads. Inspect the current setup of the application in terms of thread pools, maximum number of open connections, any limitations on resource usage, etc. Look for documentation on [performance tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_tuning) of individual middleware compoments as well.
3. Repeat your test run with a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) telemetry enabled or look at the [APM tool output](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-the-full-application-picture-with-blazemeter-and-apm-integration/) for the test time frame if the tool is in place, it will allow you do perform a deep dive into what's going on under the hood of this or that function call as it might be [inefficient algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) or a [slow database query](https://stackify.com/performance-tuning-in-sql-server-find-slow-queries/)